# will_paginate deletes posts in a group when posts are paginated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate to paginate posts within a group.
A group might have many posts and I don't want to show all posts at once.
For some strange reason I noticed that a lot of posts are deleted from the database when I do `@group.posts = paginated_posts` as displayed in * groups_controller*.

I'm not doing save on @group, why are the posts deleted?

**Tests first**

```
 69     it "Pagination – get one group and its posts" do
 70       10.times { Fabricate(:post, group: @group, user: @user) }
 71       puts "POST COUNT BEFORE #{@group.posts.count}"
 72       # byebug
 73       get group_path(@group, posts_per_page: 3)
 74       puts "POST COUNT AFTER #{@group.posts.count}"
 75       expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
 76       expect(@group).to be_present
 77     end
```

**Output from the test**

```
Groups
  GET /group/:group_id?posts_per_page=10&posts_page=2
POST COUNT BEFORE 12
POST COUNT AFTER 3
```

**groups_controller.rb**

```
  9   def show
 10     paginated_posts = @group.posts.paginate(
 11       page: params[:posts_page],
 12       per_page: params[:posts_per_page] || 100000,
 13     )
 14     @group.posts = paginated_posts
 15     render json: @group
 16   end
```

**The log**

```
  (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started GET "/groups/33?posts_per_page=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-18 12:52:13 +0000
Processing by GroupsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"posts_per_page"=>"3", "id"=>"33"}
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "78913bd2-4c72-4c73-ba75-421e154c830b"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Group Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."group_id" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["group_id", 33], ["LIMIT", 3], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."group_id" = $1  [["group_id", 33]]
   (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 156]]
  PostImage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "post_images".* FROM "post_images" WHERE "post_images"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 156]]
  Post Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 156]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 157]]
  PostImage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "post_images".* FROM "post_images" WHERE "post_images"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 157]]
  Post Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 157]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 158]]
```

Comment: Show your view too, it looks like it's getting deleted after some comments and images load and the code you provided does not show comments nor images. EDIT: also, add your Post model, maybe there's some callback doing nasty things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@group.posts = ...` doesn't work the way you think it does.  If you have a one-to-many relationship and you assign an array of associated records to the existing `group` object, the records set *and remove* the `group.id` foreign key immediately.  No save is required.

So when you do

```
@group.posts = paginated_posts
```

The paginated posts are assigned to the association *and* all other records in the association are removed from the association. Instantly.  They're not necessarily deleted, but they no longer belong to `@post`

You may want to change your `#to_json` ... perhaps add

```
attr_accessor :page_of_posts
```

And then in your controller

```
@group.page_of_posts = paginated_posts
```

And ensure `page_of_posts` is what's rendered in the json. Others may suggest a better way.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! :)